# Snuffle in PyTorch Dataloader

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a custom dataset in PyTorch that returns text and image. I have a question regarding snuffle in dataloader. Can he mix the text and the corresponding picture, that is, make the picture not match the text?

I don't know what I can do with it

Comment: What is your problem? Can you provide a minimal example to show what you would like to achieve?